# AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'task_done'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

can anyone explain why I am getting the following error?

I am using python 3.4

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/arron/Downloads/Snomed/worker/neo4j_upload_worker.py", line 36, in run
    self.queue.task_done()
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'task_done'
```

***code***

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time


class Neo4jUploadWorker(Thread):
num_worker_threads = 8
value = 0

def __init__(self, queue, item_processor):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.queue = queue
    self.tx = None
    self.idx = 0
    self.item_processor = item_processor

def run(self):
    try:
        while True:
            # Get the work from the queue and expand the tuple
            item = self.queue.get()
            if item is None:
                break
            if self.idx % 1000 == 0 and self.idx != 0:
                if self.tx is not None:
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    self.tx.commit()
                self.tx = self.item_processor.graph.cypher.begin()
                print('committed 1000 rows till row:' + str(self.idx))
            if self.idx == 0:
                self.tx = self.item_processor.graph.cypher.begin()
            self.idx += 1
            self.item_processor.process(item, self.tx)
            self.queue.task_done()
    finally:
        print('in the worker finally')
        if self.tx is not None and not self.tx.finished:
            self.tx.commit()
```

According the python 3 documentation I have called it how it should be:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()
```

with the obvious use of self.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this queue actually a `queue.Queue` queue, or is it some other queue type?

Comment: One thing I would say is don't mix concerns in your code. The queuing code should only concern itself with queuing and not processing the data. Also how are you calling it? I think you have a problem with instantiation.

Comment: `task_done` was added in version 3.4.4. What version are you using?

Comment: @ solarc I'm using 3.4

Comment: @user2357112 it is def intended to be a `queue.Queue`

Comment: @solarc: The docs say it was added in [2.5](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.task_done).

Comment: Have you edited the `queue` module in any way? If you have, don't do that. You may need to reinstall Python.

Comment: I have not edited it in any way. I'm also using a virtualenv to make sure I'm not calling any legacy modules either. that had crossed my mind too

Comment: @brucezepplin it was added to 2.x in 2.5 and 3.x in [3.4.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.task_done). What's the exact patch version you are using (3.4. **x** )?

Comment: @solarc: That's `asyncio.Queue.task_done`, not `queue.Queue.task_done`. (Of course, we can't really tell what kind of object we're dealing with here beyond the Queue name.)

Comment: Can you `print(type(self.queue).__module__)` and see where this queue's type is defined?

Comment: @solarc - its python 3.4.3

Comment: It now works. I uninstalled all versions of python (I require both 2.7 and 3.4 for different projects) and reinstalled both. I am running anything python3 within virtualenv and this now works. I appreciate that this is unsatisfactory as far as stack overflow solutions go, but at least you guys had me checking my python versions and where I was calling my modules from.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by way of ensuring that the correct version of Python was being used.